# [JWPlayer]: Play last segment of .ts from HLS?

Tags: video, video-streaming, jwplayer, red5, http-live-streaming

In `JwPlayer` Is it possible to play last segment of `.ts` from `HLS`? In this case last segment is `stream00736.ts`

current JwPlayer code:

```
jwplayer("<?php echo $this->id?>").setup({
                    autostart: <?php echo $this->autoStart?'true':'false'?> ,
                    flashplayer: "<?php echo CHtml::asset($this->_path.'/jwplayer.flash.swf')?>",
                    width:<?php echo $this->width?>,
                    height:<?php echo $this->height?>,
                    playlist: [{
                        sources: [{ 
                           //Desktop
                            file: "<?php echo $this->rtmpPath;?>"
                        },{
                            //Mobile
                            file: "<?php echo $this->hlsPath;?>"
                        }]
                    }],
                    primary:"flash",
                });
```

[image: HLS Segment]

Comment: So you meant you only want to play the last segment, none of the others?

Comment: I mean, begin from last segment. It's used for live streaming.

Comment: We do indeed support live streaming (hls). We always start with the forelast segment, to have a bit more buffer.

Comment: I have tested it with iPad and Android. In iPad, video start with the forelast (with 1 minute delay, maybe caused by long conversion process), but in Android the video played at (always) first segment of HLS.

Comment: @EthanLongTail, See edit, did something wrong with the code?

Comment: Hm, it looks OK. Can I see where this is running?

Comment: here's the stream http://180.244.230.232:5080/live/streams/test.m3u8 .  It's active right now.

Comment: and here's the stream with current jwPlayer code http://180.244.230.232:90/jwplayer/jwplayertest.php . Thanks,

Comment: @EthanLongTail in addition we use `Android 4.1.2` for the sake of testing.

Comment: Your link is down? The server at 180.244.230.232 is taking too long to respond.

Comment: @EthanLongTail it's midnight here right now and I don't have My Own IP public. I'll republish it tomorrow (about 8 more hours)

Comment: Ah, ok. We are located in NYC (EST), so Different time zones.

Comment: We've also experienced this in our enterprise account, support couldn't help us.  We've got playlists that generate 4-5 sec segments (max 30 sec playlists), JW always kicks off the segments at the end of the tail...